# What does blue highlighted text mean?

Tags: files, colors, filename

This is what I see when I run `ls` in `/var/mail`:

[image: Screenshot of ls output]

I am asking about those vbk files in particular.
Google is telling me that it's an executable, but it can't be. They should be log files. All the other logs are in normal plain text.

The files with similar names (example: `vbk201303` and `vbk2013033`) are actually the same size. Same with the other 3 files. Could the blue highlight be telling me that they are copy of each other or are they actually pointing to the same file and if I delete one of them that would also remove the others?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details, nor details of the shell being used (*which can influence how colors are shown*).   Have you look at the `stat` values of any of the files for clues?

Comment: it's saying "regular file". What does that mean?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `ls -l /var/mail/vbk2013033 /var/mail/vbk`. Just copy the text directly into your question and use the `{}` button to mark it as code.

Answer (score 0):

After I truncate the vbk2013033 it also truncated the 201303 file so the blue highlight files are files that point to the same place as an other file (not all point to the same place though). This was the answer I was looking for.